# Vim commands don't seem to be working

Tags: vim

I'm writing a sml program (a weird functional programming language) and I'm alerting my `.vimrc` file.  However, my changes don't seem to be taking effect to my files.  I can make the changes to `.vimrc` and then go to my sml file and type (`gg =G`) to try to format, but the changes don't seem to be taking effect.  For instance, I'm trying to change the size of an indent with the following lines:

```
set tabstop=150
set shiftwidth=150
set expandtab
```

and I'm trying to set the textwidth with `set textwidth=20` (the 20 is just a test number).

Why isn't my `.vimrc` file working? I believe it's in the correct location (my `~ directory`).

Here's my entire `.vimrc` file for your consideration.

```
" An example for a vimrc file.

" Maintainer:                                                                                                                                         Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:                                                                                                                                        2008 Dec 17
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"                                                                                                                                                           for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"                                                                                                                                                         for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" Andrew Patterson added these settings "
set tabstop=150
set shiftwidth=150
set expandtab
set clipboard=unnamed

if has("vms")
  set nobackup                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                " keep a backup file
endif
set history=50                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 " display incomplete commands
set incsearch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               " do incremental searching

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
" so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')


set mouse=a
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  set textwidth=20

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  " Also don't do it when the mark is in the first line, that is the default
  " position when opening a file.
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
" Only define it when not defined already.
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload your `~/.vimrc` for your changes to take effect. This is done with:

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

However, generally, when playing with settings, it's best to do work on the command-line as they take effect immediately and overwrite settings from filetype plugins:

```
:set option=value
```

You can add them to your `~/.vimrc` when they satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting tabstop and shiftwidth to 150? I seems unlikely that that's actually what you want. Try just doing `:set` by itself in normal mode from within vim to see if the values in your .vimrc are being loaded. You can also do `:echo $MYVIMRC` to make sure vim is looking in the right place. The action = takes depends on what the `equalprg` or `indentexpr` is, which is probably being changed by the sml specific vim settings loaded by `filetype plugin indent on`.

Comment: 150 is just some random test number that I was using to see if I I could see any changes.  The `:set` command shows some of the changes being loaded but not others - therefore it probably means that the plugin is changing some settings.  Do you know how to change the plugin settings?

Comment: 150 as tab stop with 80 characters/line is radically out of range, it wouldn't surprise me if vim just ignored such patent nonsense.